# How do I use the Manipulate-function with GeoGraphics?

Tags: manipulate, geographics

I'm trying to use the Manipulate function with GeoGraphics like so:

```
Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[
  Entity["HistoricalCountry", "RomanEmpire"][
   Dated["Polygon", t]]], {t, 0, 200}]
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: replace `{t, 0, 200}` with `{t, 0, 200, 1}`?

Comment: That did it, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Changing the control specification to `{t, 0, 200, 1}` fixes the issue.

For more responsive interactivity, you can create the graphics objects outside `Manipulate`:

```
polygons = Table[Entity["HistoricalCountry", "RomanEmpire"][Dated["Polygon", t]], 
  {t, 0, 200}];
```

Find longitude and latitude ranges to be used as the option value for `GeoRange` in all `GeoGraphics`:

```
georange = CoordinateBounds[Join @@@ polygons[[All, 1]]];
```

Create a list of `GeoGraphics` objects with your desired options:

```
geographics = GeoGraphics[#,
     GeoRange -> georange,
     GeoRangePadding -> Quantity[200, "Kilometers"],
     GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMapNoLabels"],
     GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular" ] & /@ polygons;
```

Use the list with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[geographics[[i + 1]], {i, 0, 200, 1}]
```

[image]